# Creating a Salt state that will be executed upon minion connection

Tags: salt-stack

I unable to find in the documentation an example of the following use case:

Minions, all of them or only a specific group - will apply some state on their own
upon system startup or restored connection..
Can I create a task in Salt that I do not need to manually apply with `state.apply` ?

I want to manage Windows boxes (not VMs) -
so not all of them are online at the time that I decide to apply some state..

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply states on system/service restart you can set [`startup_states`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#startup-states) in the minion config:

```yaml
startup_states: highstate
```

```yaml
startup_states: sls
sls_list:
  - minion_startup
```

Alternatively, you can [schedule a job](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/jobs/index.html#scheduling-jobs) to run every `N` seconds after the minion starts, which includes at startup by default:

```yaml
schedule:
  highstate:
    function: state.apply
    seconds: 3600
```

If that's not what you mean by "restored connection", then you probably want to look at [presence events](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/event/master_events.html#event-master-presence) and writing a [reactor](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/reactor/):

```yaml
presence_events: true
reactor:
  - salt/presence/change:
    - salt://reactor/presence.sls
```

```yaml
{% for minion in data["new"] %}
reconnect state:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: "{{ minion }}"
    - arg:
      - minion_startup
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to reproduce the functionality of ESET Protect solution, it provides task scheduling that is marked by agent as done and never executes it again.. And You don't need to apply this task manually, once agent boot up and connected to the server it checks for uncompleted tasks. I can not see this behavior nor in startup_states nor in reactor or scheduled jobs. Scheduled Jobs are as near as it can get, but salt-minion will not check on it's own if there are jobs that it should execute.. am I right? Thank You

Comment: That functionality is not necessary if you have a state management system like Salt does. The point of a Salt state is that it can be applied repeatedly and doesn't do anything if nothing has changed since the previous time. I don't know what you mean by "on its own". You configure what you want to be scheduled, and it runs them when the schedule says to.

Comment: If you really want a "do this exactly once" system with Salt, then use a scheduled job to check what needs doing, and a returner to confirm it was done. You'll need some custom code to connect it together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the functionality of the Saltstack [Reactor](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html) system. This allows Salt master to take actions based on events. For this we need to configure reactor and specify the [events](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/event/master_events.html) master should respond to.

When a minion starts, it triggers an event `salt/minion/<minion-id>/start`.

Example:

Reactor to respond to any minion start:

```yaml
reactor:
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':
    - salt://reactor/start.sls
```

We can apply a state or complete orchestration. Below example is to apply a state, i.e. `start.sls`. You could filter your minions further with `tgt` and `tgt_type`.

```yaml
touch_file:
  local.state.single:
  - tgt: '*'
  - arg:
    - file.touch
    - C:\Users\someuser\Documents\minion-start
```